# java.lang.NullPointerException     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.getCommandLinkOnClickScript

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a managed bean declared in session scope. There is a drop down of years and a submit button. The page works fine when I try to run the report for all years except 2011. I get the following error. What causes the error below?

```
11:53:20,280 ERROR [STDERR] May 2, 2011 11:53:20 AM com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/reports/studentInfo.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.getCommandLinkOnClickScript(RenderKitUtils.java:934)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.getOnClickScript(CommandLinkRenderer.java:295)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(CommandLinkRenderer.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(CommandLinkRenderer.java:165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:788)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:280)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:262)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:284)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeCellChildren(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:285)...
...............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was an old JSF 1.2 bug which manifested when you put in the `<h:commandLink>` a `<f:param>` whose `value` attribute was `null` or totally omitted.

E.g.

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:param name="foo" />
</h:commandLink>
```

or

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:param name="foo" value="#{null}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Apart from fixing it as such that it is never null, you can also just upgrade to the latest Mojarra 1.2 build. It's currently already at [1.2_15](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) and this bug was already fixed somewhere around version 1.2_05 which was released over 5 years ago. Keep yourself and your software up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Changing the versions helped. Actually I had the newer versions in place but were not used due to build error. So had to check the versions and it got resolved. Thanks again for the quick reply. You are a Rockstar in JSF.